# Programatically mount network location securely in Linux with Go

Tags: linux, security, go, mount

In Linux I can mount a network location programatically with Go like this:

```
func main() {
  var user, pass string
  fmt.Println("username:")
  fmt.Scanln(&user) // ignore errors for brevity
  fmt.Println("password:")
  fmt.Scanln(&pass)

  cmd := exec.Command("mount", "-t", "cifs", "-o", "username="+user+",password="+pass, "//server/dir", "media/dir")
  cmd.Run()
}
```

**The problems:**

1. I can't run this without elevating privileges with `sudo`
2. Username and password will be provided by the user. This seems very unsafe. **Can anyone confirm on the safety or danger of this approach?**

Here's a similar approach with variables:

```
cmd := exec.Command("mount", "-t", "cifs", "-o", "username=$USER,password=$PASS", "//server/dir", "media/dir")
cmd.Env = []string{"USER="+user, "PASS="+pass}
cmd.Run()
```

**That does not work.** It seems that `exec.Command()` function escapes the dollar sign, so the values in the env variables aren't replaced there. So this seems to indicate some type of safety or escaping going on here.

**Editing the `etc/fstab` file** would allow me to run `mount` without `sudo` but then I'd need `sudo` to edit the `fstab` file, so back to square one.

Comment: `exec.Command` doesn't escape the dollar signs, quite the opposite - it's your shell that does variable substitution before executing a command. Go just executes the command with the parameters you've given it. Also, problem 1 isn't a problem, it's just a statement of fact about the permissions required, same as the last statement. There's nothing Go can do to change the fundamental access controls of Linux, nor should it be able to.

Comment: This way to do things is already hosed because what's passed as arguments to a process gets exposed in the publically-accessible list of processes. Please consuls the `mount.cifs` manual page about the `credentials=filename` parameter which is the correct way to securely call `mount -t cifs`.

Comment: As to other problems (`sudo`, editing `/etc/fstab`) I'd recommend to look elsewhere. For instance, `FUSE` supports the `gvfs` backend, and this combo can be used to mount `CIFS` shares in userspace. There also exist the `smbnetfs` daemon which does a similar thing by running entirely in user space.

Comment: And one note on `credentials=filename`: using it assumes you're creating the file for it in a secure manner: that is, readable and writable only by the creating user and inaccessible by everyone else. That is, please do your research on creating temporary files in a secure way in a Unix environment.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about gvfs @kostix. It helped me figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `gvfs` to mount shares in `userspace`, which means we don't need to elevate privileges with `sudo`. The `gio` command can be used for this.

The code snippet below excludes error handling for brevity:

```golang
cmd := exec.Command("gio", "mount", "smb://server/share")
inPipe, _ := cmd.StdinPipe()
cmd.Start()

// Get credentials whichever way you find best, including scanning the Stdin.
// Concatenate them together with line breaks in between and a line break at the end.
auth := "Username\nDomain\nPassword\n"
inPipe.Write([]byte(auth))

// Wait for the command to finish.
cmd.Wait()
```

Scanning the `Stdin` seems to be an acceptable way to capture credentials, since that's how the `gio` command works.